# Ticket printing

Tags: vb.net, printing, visual-studio-2017

I'm busy to write ticket program in Vb , everything is working perfectly
but when i'm printing things goes wrong,
the ticket is printing correctly ( in this example 3 ) the ticketnumbers are overlapping 
example : 3 tickets 15200 , 15201 , 15203
3 tickets are printed but the 1520 is printed correct but on evey ticket the 1,2 a 3 are printed over each other 
What the hell is going wrong ??

this is a part of the code

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As System.Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

Dim AZ As String

Dim x As Integer

Dim LB1, LB2 As Integer

AZ = TextBox12.Text

For x = 0 To AZ - 1  
   LB1 = Val(TextBox1.Text) + x
   e.Graphics.DrawString(LB1, New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10), Brushes.Black, New Point(155, 265))
next

end sub
```

Comment: If you look at the DrawString method, you should see that it wants an X and Y coordinate. You are using the same X and Y coordinate in each iteration of the loop. Uses some math on one or both of your coordinates based off of the x value from your loop to move the Ticket Number each time.

Comment: Not sure if my edits will notify the user of my changes so commenting here to alert a change in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I misread and gave you the wrong answer.

One way I've done this in the past was to call the printdocument.print inside a loop. The only problem with this is that you get a messagebox telling you that each page is printing so that may not be ideal.

Anyway, here is a method that you might be able to work off with. It's been a while since I've used the printdocument as I find the ReportViewer/Report is easier to work with.

```
'Widen the scope of LB1 so it can be used in both methods
Dim LB1, LB2 As Integer 'Declared outside of any methods (Class Level)


Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    e.Graphics.DrawString(LB1.ToString, New Font("microsoft sans serif", 10), Brushes.Black, New Point(155, 265))
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    Dim AZ As Integer = CInt(NumericUpDown1.Value)
    For x = 0 To AZ - 1
        'We can get rid of this if we use a NumericUpDown control and set it
        'to ensure we are working with a number.
        If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, LB1) Then
            'notify the user with maybe a messagebox that the input is invalid
            Exit Sub
        End If
        LB1 += x
        PrintDocument1.Print()
    Next
End Sub
```

Again, I've not worked with this for a while but I seem to remember e.HasMorePages being a way of telling the PrintDocument to move to the next page. You might google up on it and see if it's a better alternative than looping and displaying the Print messagebox for each page like this code is doing. Hopefully it's at least gives you something to work off of.

**EDIT  --- THIS IS THE PROPER WAY OF DOING WHAT YOU'RE WANTING TO DO ---**

I decided to go ahead and look into the HasMorePages myself and It would be the better and more proper solution. You would need to change a few things but here is an example of your code using it.

```
Dim LB1, LB2 As Integer 'Declared outside of any methods
Dim currentTicket = 0

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    'how many tickets to print
    Dim TotalTickets As Integer = CInt(NumericUpDown1.Value)
    'build the current ticket number (I would look at my previous code
    'which uses TryParse instead of Val as an invalid input could cause
    'your application to fail)
    LB1 = Val(TextBox1.Text) + currentTicket
    'Print the ticket number on the page
    e.Graphics.DrawString(LB1.ToString, New Font("microsoft sans serif", 10), Brushes.Black, New Point(155, 265))
    'increase the currentTicket counter
    currentTicket += 1
    'did we go over the total number of tickets we want to print
    If currentTicket < TotalTickets Then
        'if not, we need to tell the printdocument that we have more to print
        e.HasMorePages = True
    End If
    'otherwise, we'll stop there and print the pages we produced.


End Sub
```

This will give you the single dialog that shows how many pages are being printed instead of a single dialog per page.